# Citations as footnotes?

Tags: bibtex

Is there a simple way to get citations to appear as footnotes rather than as a section at the end of the article? Preferably using bibtex.

Comment: See [How to embed citations into footnotes?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/69716/5764) (possible duplicate, although it references [`biblatex`](http://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex)).

Comment: The [footbib](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footbib/footbib.pdf) package is a BibTeX based solution that seems to do what you are asking.

Comment: footbib gives some errors... "the output routine of LaTeX changed"...

Comment: biblatex gives "incompatible package amsrefs"

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen: Perhaps you should add MWE in order to track the errors you reported.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a BibTeX based solution, you can use the `footbib` package. As instructed in the [manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/footbib/footbib.pdf), the compilation sequence is

1. `latex` *doc*
2. `bibtex` *doc.fb*
3. `latex` *doc*
4. `latex` *doc*

where *doc* is the name of your LaTeX document without the file extension. Of course, `latex` can be replaced with `pdflatex`, `lualatex`, or `xelatex`. The document states that further compilation rounds may be necessary for the result to stabilize. On the other hand, sometimes step 4 is not needed, as is the case with the following example.

[image: Output of the example code]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=16cm,paperheight=6.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{footbib}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
Citing a book~\footcite{book-full}.

\lipsum[1]

Another citation here~\footcite{whole-set}.
\footbibliographystyle{unsrt}
\footbibliography{xampl}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the need for the .fb extension. It still does not work together with the amsrefs package, it seems.

Comment: I get this error:
``The output routine of LaTeX changed since the current version of
   \`footbib'.\MessageBreak Since `footbib' patches this routine,
   using it may produce unexpected\MessageBreak results. Send a mail to \space
   Eric.Domenjoud@loria.fr \space to get a new version.\MessageBreak\MessageBreak
   Type \space X <return> \space to quit or cross your fingers and
   just type <return>``