# References in footnotes (achemso style)

Tags: bibtex, footnotes, achemso, footcite

I would like to put my references in the footnotes as in the example in the following figure ([Citations as footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200596/citations-as-footnotes)), **but using achemso style package**:

[image]

I tried several alternatives suggested on the forum but I still haven't been successful.

I tried something similar below:

```
\usepackage{footbib}
\begin{document}
    Text \footcite{ReferenceName}
    \bibliographystyle{achemso}
    \bibliography{References/References.bib}
\end{document}
```

and I am getting something similar below (with errors - ps: I'm using Overleaf):

[image]

[image]

Can you give me any advice to achieve what I'm looking for (if possible)?

Ps: **I have the achemso.bst file in the directory**.