# Why \footcite not working in beamer?

Tags: beamer, citing

I wanted to add citations in my beamer presenatation and saw following post.

[How to embed citations into footnotes?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/how-to-embed-citations-into-footnotes)

For test run I copied the answer posted there but I am not geting ciattaion as shown there. Instaed I m only getting 'foo12' at bottom of my slide.

Can any one tell me whats going wrong here. Is there any new package that i need to add for \documentclass{beamer}

Comment: Has your problem been solved by the provided answer? Then please don't forget to accept it. Otherwise try `\footfullcite` from this answer https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/416247/117274 and then report back if possible. Or have you found out how to solve the mystery yourself, then kindly answer your own question.

Answer (score 9):

You have to process your document once with pdflatex, then once with `biber` and then twice again with pdflatex.

With this example (modified from the linked question to use `beamer`):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text.\footnote{Some text in a footnote.} Some more text.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The output is:

[image]

Check your versions for `biblatex` and update if necessary. In my system, TeX Live2015, at the moment of this answer:

```
biblatex.sty    2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (PK/JW/AB)
biblatex2.sty    2015/04/19 v3.0 programmable bibliographies (biber) (PK/JW/AB)
Biber 2.1
```

Comment: I am using the .bib example from your posted answer

Comment: @NAASI Then use `biber`. Load the package as in `\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}`. Delete the auxiliary files; in particular the `.bbl` file; run the document through pdflatex; open a terminal and (assuming your `.tex` name is called `test.tex`), run `biber test` now run pdflatex twice again in the document.