# How to show cited references on the same page in beamer

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, citing

I have created a presentation using Beamer template. The presentation is a bit long with lots of references. I believe audience will find more convenience in finding cited references on the same page (at the bottom) rather than looking at the end of the presentation, for example like this

[image]

References in standard beamer template appear like this

[image]

I couldn't find any beamer template that enables us to show references on the same page. I don't know how can we make such changes. Can anybody point me in the right direction, Thanks in advance

Comment: With biblatex you can use `\footfullcite`.

Comment: see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262073/36296

Comment: @samcarter Hello, before using `\footfullcite{}` do I have to add any package or make any changes in the document. Because by just changing `\cite{}` to `\footfullcite{}` doesn't works.

Comment: `biblatex` is necessary and you need to run `biber`, see the code in the linked questions. But without seeing a [minimal working example with bibliography (MWEB)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407) it is hard to tell more.

Comment: @samcarter I am getting this error `./main.tex:221:Undefined control sequence \end{frame}`

Comment: I cannot see your code, please make a https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407 if you want help!

Comment: @samcarter See MWEB https://paste.ofcode.org/Y2SWDuaQZSffrCv4bEsebx

Comment: You are not using biblatex, please see the the link at the top of your question for the correct biblatex syntax. For more information how to switch to biblatex, see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5091/what-to-do-to-switch-to-biblatex