# Footenote in metropolis beamer theme: standard footenote layout

Tags: beamer, footnotes, beamer-metropolis

Using the metropolis theme, I am able to use footonotes with and without markers using: [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker)

```
\begin{document}
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
%\usepackage[sfdefault]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\usetheme[sectionpage=progressbar, subsectionpage = none, progressbar = frametitle]{metropolis}
\uselanguage{French}
\languagepath{French}

\usefonttheme{professionalfonts} % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif} % default family is serif
\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=white}

\newcommand\blfootnote[1]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand\thefootnote{}\footnote{#1}%
  \addtocounter{footnote}{-1}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \footnote{With marker}
  \blfootnote{Without marker}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How do I format the footnote such that It looks like in usual documents ?
Like in :

1. [Why \footcite not working in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262071/why-footcite-not-working-in-beamer)
2. [Footnote without a marker](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/30720/footnote-without-a-marker)
3. This person is also using metropolis with the footnote layout I want, but I could not catch what he changed: [How to insert a horizontal bar as a footnote at the end of a beamer slide in metropolis/mtheme?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/398806/how-to-insert-a-horizontal-bar-as-a-footnote-at-the-end-of-a-beamer-slide-in-met)