# how to remove this space in beamer + biblatex

Tags: beamer, biblatex

If I compile the following

```tex
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@article{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {Title},
  author = {H Miller},
  journal = {Journal}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}
\AtEveryCitekey{
    \clearfield{pages}
    \clearfield{issn}
    \clearfield{doi}
    \clearfield{address}
    \clearfield{volume}
    \clearfield{isbn}
    \clearfield{series}
    \clearfield{number}
    \clearfield{note}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text.\footnote{Some text in a footnote.} Some more text.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

I get a big space between footnote label `2` and the citation. If I remove the `\AtEveryCitekey` block, the space goes away, and the two footnotes are aligned. Is this a bug? How can I get rid of the space while keeping the `\AtEveryCitekey`?

(Example adapted from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/262073/193342))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in [What is the use of percent signs (%) at the end of lines? (Why is my macro creating extra space?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/35864), TeX normally treats line ends just like spaces. Within `\AtEveryCitekey` spaces are relevant (essentially `\AtEveryCitekey` is like a `\newcommand`/`\renewcommand` on an internal macro that is called whenever `biblatex` processes a citation), so every line end ends up giving you a space in the citation output.

The solution is to hide the end of lines with `%`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
    \clearfield{pages}%
    \clearfield{issn}%
    \clearfield{doi}%
    \clearfield{address}%
    \clearfield{volume}%
    \clearfield{isbn}%
    \clearfield{series}%
    \clearfield{number}%
    \clearfield{note}%
}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{foo12,
  year    = {2012},
  title   = {Title},
  author  = {H Miller},
  journal = {Journal}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text.\footnote{Some text in a footnote.} Some more text.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: 2 H Miller. “Title”. In: Journal (2012).]