# How to change Footnote color in only one slide?

Tags: beamer, color, citing

For some reason I want to change the color of my citations in my slides. I am using the code posted in here

[Why \footcite not working in beamer?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/262071/why-footcite-not-working-in-beamer)

as a MWE.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
footcite is in default color blue here.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
How to make footcite red color here.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

How can I do this? I tried using \color{red} to make citation appear in red but it didnt work.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 2):

To change the colour locally for one frame, put the commands inside e.g. `{}` in order to keep the changes within this group.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
footcite is in default color blue here.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

{
\setbeamercolor{footnote mark}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{footnote}{fg=red}
\begin{frame}
How to make footcite red color here.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}
}

\begin{frame}
    footcite is in default color blue here.\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]