# Bibliography not showing in the last slide

Tags: beamer, biblatex, bibliographies

I am writing a presentation in Beamer, with the package biblatex. To keep the (few) citations compact in the slides I used \footcite, but at the end of the presentation the usual \bibliographystyle followed by \bibliography does not work. If for example I write:

```
\begin{frame} 
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{frame}
```

I get the last slide with only "bibliography.bib" written on it. What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: My code is something like this

```
\usepackage{biblatex}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
The article \footcite{Mr. X (2000)} shows that apples are very tasty.
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
```

Where I have a bibtex file in the same Overleaf project (but printbibliograpghy does not admit arguments(?)) and I call, in the foot note, the articles as abbreviations, not as one would do with \cite{}.

Comment: These are BibTeX commands, not BibLaTeX (which would be `\printbibliography`).

Comment: So, in this case, what's the correct syntax?

Comment: Remove these two commands and use `\printbibliography` instead.

Comment: @tommy1996q You can see an example of using `\footcite` in a beamer presentation in this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/262256/36296

Comment: It doesn't work, the page remains blank. I'll update the question to be more clear

Comment: @tommy1996q Your code is missing `\addbibressource{filename.bib}` in the preamble

Comment: @tommy1996q spaces and special characters in the name of the bib entry might also not be the best of ideas...