# How to put a reference for a graphic in beamer?

Tags: beamer, graphics, citing

I am making a presentation. One of my slides has a graphical representation of statistics in a fancy manner. I want to make a reference of source from where I am pulling those stats. How can I do this.

MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file
\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{Fig_XYZ.png} 
\footcite{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

This results in an awkwardly place (towards bottom right corner of slide) number in my slide. How can I bring this number around my image?

Comment: A footnote marker is not really an obvious partner for an image, is it? Can't you just put an abbreviated reference beneath the image? Or in the footline? Footnote references to a slide somewhere else in the presentation are going to mean all of nothing to your audience, surely?

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 4):

As cfr mentioned in her comment, better looking way is not to use footnote references for pictures. Try to put reference immediately below picture like this:

[image]

```
\begin{frame}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{example-image}\\[-1ex]
{\tiny Source: \cite{foo12}}
\end{frame}
```

**Edit:**
An attempt to make command for stack of figure and citation of image source. For it I use package `stackengine`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\newcommand{\figcite}[3]{
  \def\stackalignment{l}
  \stackunder{\includegraphics[width=#1]{#2}}{\scriptsize Source: \cite{#3}}
                        }

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file

\begin{filecontents*}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents*}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

    \begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \figcite{\textwidth}{example-image}{foo12}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Do you think it is possible to have a custom `figure` enviroment that does this automatically?

Comment: @alfc, of course. See http://tex.stackexchange.com/251596/footnote-to-figure, maybe you find some idea, how to do this "semi-automaticaly", on the end you still need to write reference to your bibliography ...

Comment: Thanks, but the link is broken.

Comment: Link is not complete ...  before it you must add `http://`. Anyway, I will try to compose a new command which will a bit simplify placing figure and source note.

Comment: http is not the problem, the link is broken to me.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an addition to Zarko, I'd use `tikz`

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{memoir}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\PIC{\rule{5cm}{5cm}}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[inner sep=0pt,anchor=south west] at (0,0) {\PIC};
  \node[anchor=north west] at (0,0) {\footnotesize
    \textbf{Source:} URL};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Might be a bit simpler to understand. Of course this does not make it automatic, but it is easy to wrap it together as macro similar to `\figcite` in Zarkos answer.