# footcite , weird behaviour when citing the same reference more than once

Tags: bibliographies, citing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}% to embed the file `myreferences.bib` in your `.tex` file

\begin{filecontents}{myreferences.bib}
@online{foo12,
  year = {2012},
  title = {footnote-reference-using-european-system},
  url = {http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/69716/footnote-reference-using-european-system},
}
\end{filecontents}

% File is created and written to disk by the above package
\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

\null\vfill% to make the text height smaller for the example

\section{First section}

Some text.\footnote{Some text in a footnote.} Some more text.\footcite{foo12}
\newpage
Once more\footcite{foo12}


\end{document}
```

When I run this code, the first citation comes correctly but in the second instance, only the citation key is shown.

Any idea what might be causing this?

Answer (score 2):

From the documentation of `biblatex`, p. 69:

> **verbose**  A verbose citation style which prints a full citation similar to a bibliography entry
>   when an entry is cited for the first time, and a short citation afterwards.